# Derived query in SOQL Limits

Tags: soql, governorlimits

Let's say we have a query

```
SELECT Name
FROM Account
WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT Id FROM Settings__c WHERE Group__c = 'Test')
```

I know about 20K limitation but the question is - what is the limit for this query? How many records we are able to retrieve without hitting limits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both of the answers currently posted are incorrect. *There is no limit on the records selected by the antijoin subquery*. From the [SOQL and SOSL Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_comparisonoperators.htm#!):

> There’s no limit on the number of records matched in a subquery [note, specifically referring to a semijoin or antijoin]. Standard SOQL query limits apply to the main query.

So this query incurs the normal limit of 50,000 rows on the *main* query, but there is no row-limit impact from the antijoin subquery.

---

However... the subquery doesn't do anything as written, because the types of the Id fields don't match. An Account Id never equals the Id of some other object.

Most likely this is a typo for an Account lookup on the Settings object or an incorrect anonymization of this code.

Answer (score 0):

This are the limits:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_apexgov.htm

I don't know anything about 20k, but as per the official documentation you can retrieve 50.000 record with an SOQL query

Comment: my concern is about IN clause

Comment: It's the same. You have 2 queries, each will return a maximum of 50.000. So the IN clause (second query) will retrieve a maximum of 50.000 and the first query will have an output of max 50.000 (WHERE Id NOT IN 50.000 records)

Comment: That's not accurate. The limits do not add across those queries.

Answer (score 0):

The limit is 50k records (except for read only attribute). Only the records fetched the main query have the limit of 50K records. If you exceed this limit you will get a `LimitException`.

> In a SOQL query with parent-child relationship subqueries, each parent-child relationship counts as an extra query. These types of queries have a limit of three times the number for top-level queries. The row counts from these relationship queries contribute to the row counts of the overall code execution.

The 20K limit is the character limit for entire SOQL statement. It has been increased by 5 times to 100k characters now. This limit does not apply for subqueries or bind variables.

Please see [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/25719/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-items-in-a-soql-in-clause) for more details.

Comment: That limit does not apply - this isn't a parent child subquery.

Comment: Thank @DavidReed for correcting.